# Convert Neo4jGraphql class into one of ApolloServer's data sources

Tags: node.js, express, neo4j, graphql

I currently have a GraphQL server on top of Express.js to query from a Neo4j database using the `Neo4j GraphQL` library.

```
const typeDefs = await toGraphQLTypeDefs(sessionFactory, false);
const ogm = new OGM({ typeDefs, driver });
const neoSchema = new Neo4jGraphQL({
  typeDefs,
  driver,
  config: {
    skipValidateTypeDefs: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer({ httpServer: httpsServer }),
    ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault({ embed: true }),
  ],
  resolvers: buildResolvers(ogm, client),
});

Promise.all([neoSchema.getSchema(), ogm.init()]).then(async ([schema]) => {
  const server = new ApolloServer({ schema });
  await server.start();
  server.applyMiddleware({ app });
  await new Promise((resolve) => httpsServer.listen({ port: 4000 }, resolve));
  console.log(
    ` Server ready at ${EXPRESS_SERVER_ORIGIN}${server.graphqlPath}`
  );
});
```

How should I modify this code to make Neo4j one of the "datasources" of the ApolloServer instance like this example from the docs: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/fetching-data

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  dataSources: () => {
    return {
      moviesAPI: new MoviesAPI(),
      personalizationAPI: new PersonalizationAPI(),
    };
  },
});
```

See the full code here for more context: https://github.com/mskcc/smile-dashboard/blob/d6d9d0d24766d27da470e5aea3218a7776e2f68a/graphql-server/src/index.ts#L289C2-L289C2